# What is a right design for a such injection?

Tags: java, kotlin, guice

I have two classes of a one interface:

```
interface TimeUtils { ... }
class TimeUtilsImpl : TimeUtils { ... }
class TimeUtilsSimulation : TimeUtils { ... }
```

`TimeUtils` binding is in the module `A`:

```
bind(TimeUtils::class.java).to(TimeUtilsImpl::class.java).`in`(Singleton)
```

`TimeUtilsSimulation` binding is in the module `B`:

```
bind(TimeUtils::class.java).to(TimeUtilsSimulation::class.java).`in`(Singleton)
```

and these modules `A` and `B` are used in different binaries.

I injected `TimeUtils` in a common code like:

```
class SomeClass @Inject constructor(
  private val timeUtils: TimeUtils
)
```

And now I have a problem that when I have a request to start simulation I need to set an initial time in the `TimeUtilsSimulation` object. I can do it like this:

```
class RequestHandler @Inject constructor(
  private val someObject: SomeClass
)
onRequest(simulationStartTime: LocalDateTime) {
   if (timeUtils instanceof TimeUtilsSimulation) {
       // Set start time in a singleton timeUtils object
       (timeUtils as TimeUtilsSimulation).setStartTime(simulationStartTime)
   }
   someObject.run()
}
```

but it looks ugly.
Can you suggest something to solve this bad design?

Comment: You could have `setStartTime` in `TimeUtils` interface and have it no-op for `TimeUtilsImpl`, but it is hard to decide from the info you gave if it is the right choice.

Comment: yeah, I thought about this option. But `setStartTime` method doesn't make sense for `TimeUtilsImpl `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know Kotlin, but pure OOP speaking, the best would be to define a `TimeUtilsWrapper` interface that extends `TimeUtils` and adds `setStartTime(...)` method. Then you would have 2 classes implementing this interface:

- 1 that embeds a `TimeUtils` object with empty `setStartTime()` that delegates all other methods to the embedded object,
- second that embeds a `TimeUtilsSimulation` and delegates all methods to it, including `setStartTime()`.

Then `SomeClass` method should have a property of type `TimeUtilsWrapper` instead of `TimeUtils` and `onRequest(...)` should just always call `TimeUtilsWrapper`'s `setStartTime(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add `setStartTime` to `TimeUtils` interface and do not implement it in `TimeUtilsImpl`? It all depends on the context. For unit testing for example I think your solution would be fine. But for other, "normal" business logic is seems fishy. It's almost like the interface does not really abstract the concept properly

Comment: The last line is really the crucial one here, this looks like a badly chosen interface. As is, there's no point of IoC if this kind of logic is still to be implemented by the class using the interface. Making setStartTime a no-op would solve the control issue, but probably exposes a design flaw in the choice of interface (hard to say without more context).